# RTL8723DE bluetooth not working

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

Wi-Fi works but Bluetooth doesn’t on Ubuntu 22.04, 5.15.0-40-generic.

**lshw**

```
$ sudo lshw -class network -short
H/W path                 Device          Class          Description
===================================================================
/0/100/1d/0              eno1            network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d.1/0            wlo1            network        RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
```

**dmesg**

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth
```

returns no output.

**lsmod**

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep bt
```

returns no output.

**bluetooth service status**

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jun 27 14:28:16 beast systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jun 27 14:28:41 beast systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jun 27 14:29:09 beast systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jun 27 14:38:14 beast systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jun 27 14:41:51 beast systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jun 27 14:46:53 beast systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

I’ve tried toggling Secure and Legacy Boot in BIOS but no results. My BIOS is up-to-date.

**Contents of */lib/firmware/{rtlwifi,rtl_bt,rtw88,rtw89}***

```
$ ls /lib/firmware/{rtlwifi,rtl_bt,rtw88,rtw89} | grep 8723
rtl8723a_fw.bin
rtl8723b_fw.bin
rtl8723bs_config-OBDA0623.bin
rtl8723bs_config-OBDA8723.bin
rtl8723bs_fw.bin
rtl8723d_config.bin
rtl8723d_fw.bin
rtl8723aufw_A.bin
rtl8723aufw_B.bin
rtl8723aufw_B_NoBT.bin
rtl8723befw_36.bin
rtl8723befw.bin
rtl8723bs_ap_wowlan.bin
rtl8723bs_bt.bin
rtl8723bs_nic.bin
rtl8723bs_wowlan.bin
rtl8723bu_ap_wowlan.bin
rtl8723bu_nic.bin
rtl8723bu_wowlan.bin
rtl8723defw.bin
rtl8723fw_B.bin
rtl8723fw.bin
rtw8723d_fw.bin
```

I don’t use dual-boot.

Bluetooth hardware is fine and used to work with Windows 10.

I have BlueZ and Bluetooth packages installed.

Using `modeprobe btusb` adds the module, allowing to start the service. But `bluetoothctl devices` returns no output.

---

**Edit:**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:03d2 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg retuns no output as mentioned earlier. But after `modprobe btusb`, returns

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[ 2449.651756] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 2449.651796] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[ 2449.651797] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 2449.651802] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 2449.651804] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 2449.651808] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 2475.797043] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 2475.797046] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 2475.797049] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: Hm, the BT device is not seen. Is fast startup in Windows disabled? And check if BT isn't disabled in BIOS. MAybe reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: I don’t use dual-boot. I only have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed. I checked BIOS and it doesn’t provide any option to toggle BT. I turned off Secure boot and cleared the key. I also toggled SGX to check if it’s the culprit but turns out not.

Comment: The device should be seen in `lsusb`.

Comment: The device is supported by Linux, but it is not seen on hardware level for some reason. It is not a driver/firmware issue.

Comment: Wi-Fi worked right away after Ubuntu installation but Bluetooth did not.

Comment: Nothing shows up in Additional Drivers; I do have the Windows drivers for Bluetooth but I don’t know how to install them. I tried using ndiswrapper but the package isn’t supported anymore.

Comment: Instead of putting `Fix` in your question, you should submit the procedure you followed as an answer and you can also mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstallation of Ubuntu in non-CSM mode fixed the issue.